# Cast object to generic type at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm using reflection to call a generic method, this method returns an object which I'd like to cast to call a method on after.

```
public static string GetTableName(this ObjectContext context, Type T)
{
    var method = typeof(ObjectContext).GetMethod("CreateObjectSet", new Type[]{});
    var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(T);
    var objectSet = generic.Invoke(context, null);

    var sqlString = objectSet.ToTraceString(); 
    // doesn't work because ToTraceString() isn't a method of object
    // it's a method of ObjectSet<T>
    ...
}
```

T isn't known until runtime. How can I cast objectSet to ObjectSet<T> to be able to call ToTraceString()?

Comment: You have to use even more reflection to invoke anything on `objectSet`.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can structure your program in such a way that you will never need either casting or reflection. Look for functional programming and F#.

Comment: Have you considered dynamic references?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [TyCobb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359157/tycobb) said, you have use even more reflection. Keep going until you get to some type that you can write the cast for, like `string`:

```
public static string GetTableName(this ObjectContext context, Type T)
{
    var method = typeof(ObjectContext).GetMethod("CreateObjectSet", new Type[] { });
    var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(T);
    var objectSet = generic.Invoke(context, null);

    var toTrace = typeof(ObjectSet<>).MakeGenericType(T).GetMethod("ToTraceString");
    var sqlString = (string)toTrace.Invoke(objectSet, null);

    //...
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

(Adding my 2 cents for the sake of completeness)

The answer is "cast to an interface".

Say you have a generic class (that you control) and you would like to cast an object to it, without knowing the `<T>` so you can call some method/property.

```
public class MyThing<T>
{
    //the method you want to call after casting
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Usually the best option is to use an interface, and cast to an interface

```
public class MyThing<T> : IMyThing // <-- add this
{
    //the method you want to call after casting
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}

public interface IMyThing
{
    public void DoStuff();
}

//now you can cast unknown object to IMyThing and call `DoStuff()`
((IMyThing)unknownObject).DoStuff();
```